# SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() returns : Specified object must be part of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, v8

I have been using a script for two years from different computers with different user accounts -no problems.

> From February the 19th : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

> started returning error :  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

> intermittently for different users.

Anyone ever had the same trouble?

Thanks for your help!

Code Sample :

```
nameSheetInterfaceCariste = "Interface Cariste"
nameSheetInterfaceCaristeUn = "Interface Cariste 1"
nameSheetInterfaceCaristeDeux= "Interface Cariste 2"
function caristeCancel() 
{

  var nameSheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var responseUn = ui.alert('La localisation Initiale était-elle exacte?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  
  var raison;

  if (responseUn == ui.Button.YES) 
  {
    var responseDeux = ui.alert("La Description de l'objet était-elle suffisante?", ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if (responseDeux == ui.Button.YES) 
    {

      raison = Browser.inputBox('Décrivez la raison de votre refus');
    }
    else if  (responseDeux == ui.Button.NO)
    {
      raison = "La Description de l'objet n'était pas suffisante. Veuillez reformuler votre requête plus précisément."
    }
  } 
  
  if (raison != 'cancel' && responseUn != ui.Button.CLOSE && responseDeux != ui.Button.CLOSE)
  {
     
    if (nameSheetActive == nameSheetInterfaceCaristeUn || nameSheetActive == nameSheetInterfaceCaristeDeux)
    {
      supprimerDemandes(nameSheetInterfaceCariste, raison) 
    }
    else{
        supprimerDemandes(nameSheetInterfaceCaristeUn, raison); 
        supprimerDemandes(nameSheetInterfaceCaristeDeux, raison); 
      }
  }
}
```

**Follow up**  : as of 20/03/2020 I still get errors for some users at different moment of the day. This script is executing around 400 times a day and it throws an error 3-4 times a day.
When it happens, it seems to resolve by itself after opening/closing the document and/or waiting and trying again.

[image: error_report]

Comment: Also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-apps-script-community/wnZGdWxe_Aw

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've enabled V8 and now I get intermittently "An unexpected error has occured" for the same lines of code. Will keep you posted!

Comment: Could you share a sample of your script? Maybe there are other functions or lines of code interfering with this method and causing this error.

Comment: I've added a code sample, basically I'm asking questions to the user before checking the name of it's sheet and 'supprimerDemandes(sheetName, reason)' will behave regarding those two inputs

Comment: Hi! You have an issue in your script. In the last two ```else``` one ```else``` is inside the other which causes an error. Please remove the wrapping ```else``` to run the function without any errors. Let me know if you did not understand something.

Comment: totally understand, it was a cut and paste error. Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Did removing this wrong conditionals work? Is your issue solved after my suggestion?

Comment: Hi! I've resolved the wrong conditionals, but I still get the error sometime. I've edited the post with more details. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Hi! Are you creating any sheet somewhere else on this script? Are more than 30 different users logging at the same time? Is the error only occurring to certain users or is it completely random who gets the error? I am just trying to check first if you are going over any of Google's quotas as this is a strange behaviour. You can check [HERE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) the rest of the quotas and limitations to make sure this is not where the error is coming from. Thanks!

Comment: No sheets are created, there is an average of 5 users logging at the same time. It occurs to all users at different times (even I got the error while making tests). I've just had a look at the quotas and it shouldn't exceed any of them. This file basically just manipulate data inside one google sheet. The business is closed for 3 weeks now, I'll post updates if it's still happening after this delay. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi ! I have tried to reproduce your issue using the piece of code you have left in the answer but for me it was working correctly (I guess it only happens sometimes). Also it does not seem to be an issue with exceeding any limitations. Could you please try to change ```getActiveSheet()``` with ```getSheetByName``` (*I know this is not your actual intention but this is more to spot the issue*) and run it in your environment to see if you keep getting a similar error? **I want to basically make sure this is a problem with ```getActiveSheet()``` as this might be a bug**.

Comment: This bug is intermittent, I just tried replacing getActiveSheet() with getSheetByName and it worked perfectly fine in both cases. While it was bugging, I tried coding this simple line : var = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() and it was throwing an error. I also tried var = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(), still throwing error. Closed an reopen the document, no error for those two new lines...

Comment: Yes, then it seems to be exclusively related to ```getActiveSheet()```. Could you please share a copy of the sheet that is getting these errors ( without any sensitve data) or any other sheet that has gotten the same errors you are reporting? I am just trying to see if I can reproduce this issue and see why is this happening. Also, if you can't share, could you describe me the steps you took on creating this spreadsheet as detailled as possible? Thanks !!

Comment: I can't share this sheet since there is sensitive data. It's the only one of my sheet (and the most solicited) throwing this error. The sheet was created with 1. right click in the drive 2. New google sheet. As you mentionned, next time it throws the error, I'll try to replace the getActiveSheet() by getSheetByName("aSheetName") and post the behavior.

Comment: I've just did validation in the same spreadsheet, this new error occured while I was doing tests: 
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getActiveSpreadsheet on object SpreadsheetApp.

Comment: Closed and opened the document, the error never occured again...

Comment: Maybe it happened because you had your document opened for a long time. ```getActiveSpreadsheet``` might give issues if the document is left opened for a considerable period of time.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense since this file is used all day long. Is it a known issue? Should I make a new bug report to google support for this? Thanks a lot for your support Mateo.